# Firebase + PHP - Cloud Firestore

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to connect my PHP Project in Cloud Firestore, I am using the example link: 
**https://github.com/artimann/firebase-php/blob/master/Users.php**

Dnd using the SDK:

**https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html**

But I'm being connected to the RealTime database, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the [google-cloud-php-firestore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-firestore) `FirestoreClient`, instead.

because what you have there, clearly reads `firebase-php`.

the [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php-firestore#sample) there even uses a `users` collection.